# How can I use Kotlin default methods with Spring Data repository interfaces?

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-data

Consider the following repository interface declaration:

```
interface KotlinUserRepository : Repository<User, String> {

  fun findById(username: String): User

  fun search(username: String) = findById(username)
}
```

I'm declaring a default interface method `search(…)` that defaults to invoking `findById(…)`.

Starting my application fails with:

`org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property Search found for type User!`

How can I use Kotlin default methods with Spring Data repository interfaces and prevent `PropertyReferenceException`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### TL;DR

Kotlin 1.1/1.2 compiles default methods to abstract interface methods in the first place. It's not possible to use Kotlin's default methods in Spring Data repository interfaces.

### Explanation

Kotlin allows default interface methods with a Java runtime version 1.6. JVM-level default interface methods were introduced with Java 1.8. This causes Kotlin to use a different approach to compile default interface methods than Java does.

The code from `KotlinUserRepository` compiles to:

```
interface KotlinUserRepository extends Repository {

  User findById(String username);

  User search(String username);

  @Metadata(…)
  public static final class DefaultImpls {

    public static User search(KotlinUserRepository $this, String username) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(username, "username");
      return $this.findById(username);
    }
  }
}
```

The method `search(…)` compiles to an abstract interface method. The implementation bit compiles to a class `DefaultImpls` which reflects the default method signature. A class wanting to implement `KotlinUserRepository` is required to implement `search(…)`. Using the interface in a pure Kotlin environment will let the Kotlin compiler create the implementation bits.

Spring Data repositories work with proxies underneath. Every method on a repository must be either:

1. Implemented by the store-specific repository.
2. Implemented by a custom implementation.
3. A Java 8 default method.
4. Be annotated with a query annotation.
5. Fit the method naming scheme to allow query derivation.

In this case, `search(…)` is not implemented by any custom code according to how you'd implement a Java interface. Spring Data attempts to derive a query and considers `search(…)` as property of the `User` domain class. Lookup fails and throws `PropertyReferenceException`.

This is a known limitation.

#### References

- [DATACMNS-1223 - Kotlin interface default methods are considered query methods](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1223).
- [KT-4779 - Generate default methods for implementations in interfaces](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4779).

Answer (score 11):

As Ben pointed out, you can now (Kotlin 1.2.40+) use `@JvmDefault`.

```
interface BatchRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Batch, Long> {
    fun getAllByOrderByPriorityAscNameAsc(): List<Batch>

    @JvmDefault
    fun getForAdmin() = getAllByOrderByPriorityAscNameAsc()
}
```

You will need to enable the option in you build.gradle using something like this:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xenable-jvm-default']
    }
}
```

I just tested it on Kotlin 1.2.41 and it works.

Comment: For me it was ['-Xjvm-default=enable']; see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-default/index.html
Thanks for pointing the way :)

Comment: If you set the compiler flag `-Xjvm-default=all`, you don't have to use the `@JvmDefault` annotation.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW [Kotlin extension methods](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) worked nicely for me here, 1 .kt file:

```kotlin
interface FooRepository : JpaRepository<FooDb, UUID>

object FooRepositoryExtensions {

  fun FooRepository.doFoo(something: String): FooDb { 
      // do whatever you want here, the 'FooRepository' instance is available via `this`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The recently released Kotlin 1.2.40 now supports an experimental feature enabling compilation of Kotlin default methods to Java 8 default methods via the `@JvmDefault` annotation and setting of the feature flag: `Xenable-jvm-default`

https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/04/kotlin-1-2-40-is-out/#more-5922

I haven't tried it out yet, but your example theoretically *should* work like so:

```
interface KotlinUserRepository : Repository<User, String> {

  fun findById(username: String): User

  @JvmDefault
  fun search(username: String) = findById(username)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@JvmDefault` is now deprecated. Works fine:

```
build.gradle.kts
  kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs += listOf("-Xjsr305=strict", "-Xjvm-default=all")
  }
```

and

```
@JvmDefaultWithCompatibility
interface KotlinRepository<User> : JpaRepository<User, Int?> {

   fun getExisted(id: Int): User = findById(id).orElseThrow { 
              NotFoundException("Entity with id=$id not found") }
```

You need both of jvm option `-Xjvm-default=all` and annotation `@JvmDefaultWithCompatibility` above interface.